# Writing a regular expression to capture signed integers

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a file containing integers formatted as this example (for benchmarking a DPLL algorithm):

```
-486 535 0
-563 745 0
125 -430 512 -4 512 -4 0
512 -4 0
667 -19 0
40 -281 512 -4 0
-231 637 0
```

In general the data are formatted like that

```
number number number 0
numbers are separated by space and each line ends with the character 0,
```

for instance
this could be a string that I want to parse

```
545 -565 7 55 0
```

I want to capture each of thiese numbers.

- 545 would be the first
- -565 the second
- 7 the third
- 55 the fourth

and 0 is for separatting those numbers

Can anybody give me the regular expression to do that using java?

The code I m using is:

```
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d*)\\s*(\\-?\\d*)\\s*(\\-?\\d*)\\s*0");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sCurrentLine);
                //System.out.print("hou find one");
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    int id;
                    boolean val;
                    int i=1;
                    Clause tempClause = new Clause(counter);
                    do
                    {
                        id = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(i));
                        val = id>0;
                        if (val == false)id*=-1;
                        tempClause.addLiteral(new Literal (id,val));

                        System.out.print("id "+id+" the current i:"+i+".\n");
                        i++;
                    }
                    while (i<3);
                this.clauses.add(tempClause);
                counter++;
                System.out.print("the i:"+i+"\n");
                }
```

With this code I capture 3 integers, I need to improve to capture all the integers in that string.

Comment: Is it required that you use regex?

Comment: The regex is as simple as `-?\d+`.

Comment: I ll edit the post to show you the code I m using

Comment: Use two steps. A regex to get the whole number line `(?s)\s*(.+?)\s+0\b` then split on whitespace `\s+`

Comment: Could you use a `Scanner`? I would think `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` would be perfect for this.

Comment: So you don't care what the numbers are or how many there are, you just want to know if the line follows this pattern in a regex?

Comment: can you give me the code to do that? please.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to capture those integers, and then solve a SAT instance for the upcoming code.

Comment: @AnixPasbesoin If you want to capture the numbers you don't need to validate them e.g. with a regex, you can just read them which will also validate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `Scanner`:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int i = scanner.nextInt();
        if (i != 0)
            integers.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(integers);
}
```

**data.txt**

```
-486 535 0
-563 745 0
125 -430 512 -4 512 -40
512 -4 0
667 -19 0
40 -281 512 -4 0
-231 637 0
```

**Output**

```
[-486, 535, -563, 745, 125, -430, 512, -4, 512, -40, 512, -4, 667, -19, 40, -281, 512, -4, -231, 637]
```

Comment: I need to get the integers of each line, the character 0 is in the end of the line.

Comment: @DavidWallace, yes, I forgot about the negative numbers :)

Answer (score 2):

A test implemented for running above requirements

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testRegex {


    @Test
    public void testIntRegex() {

        Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+)");

        String example = "545 -565 7 55 0";

        Matcher matcher = intsOnly.matcher(example);
        while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println(matcher.group() + " -- ");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, the OP doesn't seem clear if any of these can be embedded between alpha chars. If so, yours is the way to go.. +1

Answer (score 0):

It could be fairly simple.

Loop through the file matching this regex.
The take the contents of capture group 1 each time and
split on whitespaces (using `"\\s+"`)

```
 # "(?s)\\s*(.+?)\\s+0\\b"

 (?s)
 \s* 
 ( .+? )                       # (1)
 \s+ 0 \b
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 10 ) 
-486 535 0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
-486 535  
----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 10 , len 12 ) 

-563 745 0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 12 , len 8 ) 
-563 745  
----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 22 , len 35 ) 

125 -430 512 -4 512 -40
512 -4 0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 24 , len 31 ) 
125 -430 512 -4 512 -40
512 -4  
----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 57 , len 11 ) 

667 -19 0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 59 , len 7 ) 
667 -19  
----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 68 , len 18 ) 

40 -281 512 -4 0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 70 , len 14 ) 
40 -281 512 -4  
----------------
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 86 , len 12 ) 

-231 637 0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 88 , len 8 ) 
-231 637
```